# Calling fetch from Nuxt.js to firebase function resuting in CORS error

Tags: firebase, cors, nuxt.js

I have the following simple code for testing purposes but when I run it I am get the CORS origin error. Is it because I am doing a POST call? I have tried everything but no luck

I tested the function in cloud console and it works, so the firebase function is fine. But there is some bug in the nuxt fetch function I think causing the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Firebase function node.js (index.js file):

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// Allow cross-origin requests
const cors = require("cors")({
  origin: true,
});
admin.initializeApp();
exports.askQuestionIntent = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, async () => {
      console.log("yeeeeeee")
  });
});
```

Here is me calling that function on my front end (Nuxt.js, store file):

```js
export const actions = {
  async askQuestion({ commit, state }, value) {
    console.log(value);
    const firebaseRest =
      "https://us-central1-abc.cloudfunctions.net/askQuestionIntent";
    let res = await fetch(firebaseRest, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(messagePrompts),
    });
    let data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
  },
};
```

And here is the error in console:

```
356594730026402389:1 Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-abc.cloudfunctions.net/askQuestionIntent' from origin 'https://www.mysite.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
4ad7630.js:1          
POST https://us-central1-abc.cloudfunctions.net/askQuestionIntent net::ERR_FAILED
    (anonymous) @ 4ad7630.js:1
    v @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    (anonymous) @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    (anonymous) @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    r @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    l @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    (anonymous) @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    (anonymous) @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    askQuestion @ 4ad7630.js:1
    (anonymous) @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    m.dispatch @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    dispatch @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    askQuestion @ d3a30f6.js:1
    ee @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    n @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    Dr.c._wrapper @ 6d77cfc.js:2
    4ad7630.js:1                  
    Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG solution found. You need to add your own invoked in the cloud console settings. See post here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/395#issuecomment-605025572